# Which arithemetical operations can I perform exactly in IEEE 754 if I limit myself to half-integers?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, arithmetic-expressions

Integers (up to some maximum magnitude which is more than large enough for my purposes) and half-odd-integers can be represented exactly in the IEEE 754 formulation of floating point numbers, so am I correct in thinking that addition and subtraction of these numbers is exact (since the result is another integer or half-odd-integer)?

Is the modulus operation (e.g., in Python, 1.0 % 0.5 == 0.0) also guaranteed to be exact?

And multiplication, since 1/4 = 0.25, 1/8 = 0.125, etc. also have exact representations?

It's easy to find problematic divisions: (e.g. 0.5/0.75) but is there a simple way to identify the class of exact divisions within these numbers?

Comment: In `double`, all half-integers of magnitude <= 2^52 are representable exactly. Their sum and difference is exact if it remains within that magnitude. Multiplication of half-integers with magnitude <= 2^25 is exact. This margin is too small for a discussion of division.

Comment: The modulus operation is *always* exact in Python if both operands have the same sign. (Excluding corner cases like NaNs, infinities, division by zero, etc.)